# How to auto insert user_id in a table in database, every morning 7:00 o'clock?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am learning laravel and facing a problem,I have a table called Employee timesheet, which stores the daily in_time and out_time of a employee.
But thing is, every morning data should go into a new column so i have made timestamps unique i.e.

```
    $user_timesheet = Timesheet::where('user_id', $user)->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->first();
```

I wanna know that how to automatically insert all the employees id in database so that it creates the timestamp.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: ___every morning data should go into a new column___ If that is really what you have designed then there is your problem. This is a terrible database design idea. Take a few minutes to read a Relational Database Design tutorial or 2 before you start a database

Comment: CRON JOBS in LARAVEL

Answer (score 0):

Pawan, If you are on live server, There you can create cron jobs to perform the task at every morning at 7:00 o'clock.
For more you can see this page - https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/

Comment: No sir, i am not on a live server, i am just learning laravel and new to this.

Comment: Why does a CRON job depend upon the server being live ?? Any *nix will run a cron job, assuming the machine is turned on at that time. And if its Windows then Task Scheduler will do the same

Comment: Dear RiggsFolly, You are right but not all users have *nix system, People also use windows system. as Pawan said, He is working on local system.